# Handling NULLs in CASE statement

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql query:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN roomid = 1 THEN SUM(taxmoney) END END AS 'total1',
       CASE WHEN roomid = 2 THEN SUM(taxmoney) END AS 'total2', 
       DATE_FORMAT(end_at,'%Y-%m-%d') AS 'date_time' FROM match_logs GROUP BY 
       DATE_FORMAT(end_at,'%Y-%m-%d')
```

And this is my result when executed it:

```
total1 || total2 || date_time
52040  || NULL   || 2015-03-31
89803  || NULL   || 2015-04-01
45250  || 4658   || 2015-04-02
```

I want to change `NULL` in `total2` column as `0`. What should i do?

Thanks all!

Comment: then `coalesce(sum(taxmoney), 0)`

Comment: apart from making null as 0 a better way would be `sum( case when roomid = 1 THEN taxmoney else 0 end) as 'total1',.....`

Answer (score 1):

Use this command for total2:

```
 CASE WHEN roomid = 2 THEN IFNULL(SUM(taxmoney),'0') END AS 'total2',
```

The complete command:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN roomid = 1 THEN SUM(taxmoney) END AS 'total1',
       CASE WHEN roomid = 2 THEN IFNULL(SUM(taxmoney),'0') END AS 'total2', 
       DATE_FORMAT(end_at,'%Y-%m-%d') AS 'date_time' FROM match_logs GROUP BY 
       DATE_FORMAT(end_at,'%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: Do we really need ``END`` 2 times ?? Its typo by OP it seems.